# How to fix an overheating laptop issue?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, shutdown, laptop-repair

Whenever i try to export my video in HitFilm express my laptop shutdown automatically with a fan noise.

I bring it to a mechanic who change the thermal paste and add a cooling pad. I resett my pc and install new window but still it's not working. Dell 7th Gen Core I7. Processor 2.70 GHz. RAM 8GB. Window 10.

Comment: There is an after market of **Laptop Coolers** because this is such a common problem. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, try running the application at a lower priority.

- Run [Sysinternals (Microsoft) Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer#download) as Administrator.
- Find the process(es) from *HitFilm* using so much CPU time.
- Right click on one process at a time.
- Select *Set Priority >*.
- Select a *lower* priority than currently set.

[image: Reduce process priority]

This might not work, if interrupting the process causes it to crash or lose its place. And, of course, this is likely to slow processing a bit.